# Building a math expression evaluator

Tags: c++, expression

I can't use boost::spirit in my environment. But I would like to use STL and boost as much as possible to build my own expression evaluator. Is there such an alternative to boost::spirit?

Comment: roll your own? CoCo/R? flex/bison? lex/yacc? ANTLR? Of course the evaluator isn't included, but should be trivial given a solid grammar

Comment: @sehe Thanks. I think I know some of the parser generators you mentioned but I thought they are generating c or c-like code. Is there anything using at least STL?

Comment: [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/libs/proto/) is Boost's expression evaluator library; Boost.Spirit is a _parsing_ library (which is built on top of Boost.Proto).

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks. I will try it out but doubt it may work in my platform though.

Comment: @Paul: If you are working on a platform where common libraries like `Boost.Spirit` isn't available, mind telling us what platform you are working on (or what additional constraints constrai your usage of libraries)? That would make it easier to suggest libraries which might work on your platform. It might also be a good idea to tell us a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish (aka how complex you expect your expressions to get)

Comment: @Grizzly and jared Krumsie, sorry for late reply but for some reason, I didn't get notification of your comment. Basically, I want to build a small matrix expression evaluator on top of mathematical expression evaluator. In theory, it should be easy but I found not in reality. I will look at the ExprTk which looks good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code includes unit tests and a complete parser I wrote in an about 90 minute session at ACCU 200x (8 or 9). If you need more, it might be easy enough to extend. You can make it do doubles by defining `Parse::value_type`, or extracting it into a separate header file and make it a template class.

Or you can take the test cases and try yourself. (it uses CUTE from http://cute-test.com)

```
#include "cute.h"
#include "ide_listener.h"
#include "cute_runner.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

namespace {

class Parser {
    typedef int value_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type> valuestack;
    typedef std::vector<char> opstack;
    typedef std::map<std::string,value_type> memory;
public:
    memory  variables;
    private:
    void evaluateSingleOperator(char op,value_type &result,value_type operand) {
        switch(op) {
            case '+': result += operand; break;
            case '-': result -= operand; break;
            case '*': result *= operand; break;
            case '/': result /= operand; break;
            default: throw("invalid operand");
        }
    }
    void evaluateStacks(valuestack &values, opstack &ops) {
        while(ops.size() && values.size()>1) {
            char op = ops.back(); ops.pop_back();
            value_type operand = values.back(); values.pop_back();
            evaluateSingleOperator(op,values.back(),operand);
        }
    }
    bool higherPrecedenceOrLeftAssociative(char last, char current) {
        return (last == current)||(last == '*' || last == '/') ;
    }
    bool shouldEvaluate(char op,opstack const &ops) {
        return ops.size() > 0 && higherPrecedenceOrLeftAssociative(ops.back(),op);
    }
    std::string parseVariableName(std::istream &is) {
        std::string variable;
        char nextchar=0;
        while ((is >> nextchar) && isalpha(nextchar)) {
            variable += nextchar;       
        } 
        if (variable.size() == 0) throw std::string("internal parse error");
        is.unget();
        return variable;    
    }
    int peekWithSkipWhiteSpace(std::istream &is) {
        int nextchar = EOF;
        while(isspace(nextchar = is.peek())) is.get();
        return nextchar;
    }
    value_type getOperand(std::istream &is) {
        int nextchar = peekWithSkipWhiteSpace(is);
        if (nextchar == EOF) throw std::string("syntax error operand expected");
        if (isdigit(nextchar)){
            value_type operand=0;
            if (!(is >> operand)) throw std::string("syntax error getting number") ;
            return operand;
        } else if ('(' == nextchar) {
            is.get();
            return parse(is);
        } else if (isalpha(nextchar)) {
            std::string variable= parseVariableName(is);
            if( parseAssignmentOperator(is)) {
                variables[variable] = parse(is);
            } else {
                if (!variables.count(variable)) throw std::string("undefined variable: ")+variable;
            } 
            return variables[variable]; 
        }
        throw std::string("syntax error");          
    }
    bool parseAssignmentOperator(std::istream &is) {
        int nextchar = peekWithSkipWhiteSpace(is);
        if ('=' != nextchar) {
            return false;
        }
        is.get();
        return true;
    }
    public:
    value_type parse(std::istream &is) {
        is >> std::skipws;
        valuestack values;
        opstack ops;
        values.push_back(getOperand(is));
        char op=')';
        while((is  >>op) && op != ')') {
            if (shouldEvaluate(op, ops)) {
                evaluateStacks(values, ops);
            }
            values.push_back(getOperand(is));
            ops.push_back(op);
        }
        evaluateStacks(values,ops);
        return values.back();
    }
    value_type eval(std::string s) {
        std::istringstream is(s);
        return parse(is);
    }
};
int eval(std::string s) {
    return Parser().eval(s);
}
void shouldThrowEmptyExpression() {
    eval("");
}
void shouldThrowSyntaxError() {
    eval("()");
}
void testSimpleNumber() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(5,eval("5"));
}
void testSimpleAdd() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(10,eval("5 +5"));
}
void testMultiAdd() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(10,eval("1   +    2 + 3+4"));
}
void testSimpleSubtract() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(5,eval("6-1"));
}
void testTenPlus12Minus100() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(-78,eval("10+12-100"));
}
void testMultiply() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(50,eval("10*5"));
}
void testDivision() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(7,eval("21/3"));
}
void testAddThenMultiply() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(21,eval("1+4 *5"));
}
void testAddThenMultiplyAdd() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(16,eval("1+4*5 -5"));
}
void testAddSubSub() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(-4,eval("1+2-3-4"));
}
void testSimpleParenthesis() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(1,eval("(1)"));
}
void testSimpleOperandParenthesis() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(2,eval("1+(1)"));
}
void testParenthesis() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(5,eval("2*(1+4)-5"));
}
void testNestedParenthesis() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(16,eval("2*(1+(4*3)-5)"));
}
void testDeeplyNestedParenthesis() {
    ASSERT_EQUAL(8,eval("((2*((1+(4*3)-5)))/2)"));
}
void testSimpleAssignment() {
    Parser p;
    ASSERT_EQUAL(1, p.eval("a=1*(2-1)"));
    ASSERT_EQUAL(8, p.eval("a+7"));
    ASSERT_EQUAL(1, p.eval("2-a"));
}
void testLongerVariables() {
    Parser p;
    ASSERT_EQUAL(1, p.eval("aLongVariableName=1*(2-1)"));
    ASSERT_EQUAL(42, p.eval("AnotherVariable=7*(4+2)"));
    ASSERT_EQUAL(1, p.eval("2-(aLongVariableName*AnotherVariable)/42"));
}
void shouldThrowUndefined() {
    eval("2 * undefinedVariable");
}
void runSuite(){
    cute::suite s;
    //TODO add your test here
    s.push_back(CUTE_EXPECT(CUTE(shouldThrowEmptyExpression),std::string));
    s.push_back(CUTE_EXPECT(CUTE(shouldThrowSyntaxError),std::string));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleNumber));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleAdd));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testMultiAdd));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleSubtract));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testTenPlus12Minus100));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testMultiply));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testDivision));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testAddThenMultiply));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testAddSubSub));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testAddThenMultiplyAdd));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleParenthesis));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleOperandParenthesis));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testParenthesis));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testNestedParenthesis));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testDeeplyNestedParenthesis));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testSimpleAssignment));
    s.push_back(CUTE(testLongerVariables));
    s.push_back(CUTE_EXPECT(CUTE(shouldThrowUndefined),std::string));
    cute::ide_listener lis;
    cute::makeRunner(lis)(s, "The Suite");
}

}
int main(){
runSuite();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YACC++ is a very good tool for parser generator for c++ applications. ANTLR is also agood option howver that does not have good documentation for its usage in C/C++.